# Suspend problem on an AMD device

Tags: suspend, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I'm running xUbuntu 16.04 on an asus device with a processor AMD A6-7310. The problem is that I can't suspend the computer. When I put the screen on the keyboard,  the screen becomes black, but the fans are still running, as well as the backlight. When I open the screen back, the screen is still black, the backlight stops, and the fans are still running. Then, I need to press a button to come back to the login screen that appears in a second.

Do you know how I can solve my problem ? I tried to set the option "nomodeset" during the boot, but the problem is still the same.

Thank you!

Here are some useful commands:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1566
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] (rev 40)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 156b
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1537
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 39)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1580
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1581
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1582
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1583
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1584
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1585
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b52b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:b721 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5590 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and [here is](https://pastebin.com/uuq8nqQu) a link to the `lshw` command.

**EDIT**
I tried to set in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
```

and then I ran `sudo update-grub` and reboot, but the problem is the same after...

Comment: Try running sudo pm-suspend in terminal and tell us what happens.

Comment: Hum interesting, pm-suspend seems to work! Just one problem, it does not lock the screen. Do you know how to use pm-suspend when I close the screen ?

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I feel so stupid. I don't know why, but xubuntu was set-up to lock the screen when I close the light, instead of suspend it. That's why `sudo pm-suspend` worked without any trouble... I just changed it in `System Preference`/`Energy saving`, and now everything works perfectly.